# How can i prevent the form update from inspect changes

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form where i have 4 fields all are disabled when window load code is give below:

```
<form action="user" method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}

    <input type="text" class="hide first" value="{{$data->name}}"  name="name" id="name">
<input type="text" class="hide second" value="{{$data->age}}"  name="age" id="age">
    <input type="text" class="hide third" value="{{$data->city}}"  name="city" id="city">
    <input type="text" class="hide fourth" value="{{$data->class}}"  name="class" id="class">
    <input type="text" class="hide first" value="{{$data->lname}}"  name="lastname" id="name">

</form>
```

Script for getting the result from the table:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.hide').attr('disabled', true);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/getdata",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#upd').click(function() {
                    $.each(data, function(i, val) {

                        var getdata = val.split(",");
                        $('.' + getdata).attr('disabled', false);

                        $('.' + getdata).css('background-color', 'white');
                        $('.' + getdata).attr("style", "background-color:white!important");

                    })
                })
            }

        });
    })
</script>
```

ajax url from where it get the data:

```
function getdata(Request $request) {

    $data = DB::table('demo') - > first();
    $result = array_keys((array) $data, 1);
    return response() - > json($result);
}
```

json response: `[ " first "," second "]`

Controller function from where i would updated my records:

```
function save_record(Request $request) {

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($request - > all());
    exit;
}
```

In all of the code i am aple to disabled all the fields which i have recieved from the function and when i edit the text value and submit the form in that case its showing me only that field which is not disabled from my jquery.

my problem is that when anyone remove the disabled attribute from the inspect and update the field in that case also the form submitted with the changed value but i dont want it..

so how can i update those value which i was recieving from the post not from the inspect chnage ..how can i prevent the form from the inspect changes can anyone please help me related this

Comment: Using two Laravel versions?

Comment: Yes using laravel version 5.2

Comment: IMHO the easiest way to make sure your users don't tamper with your input's attributes is to not show them in the first place

Comment: If this question is only about disabling the inspect tool, you cannot.

Comment: No its about which fields i am geeting only those value can updated

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides a nice way to protect `Mass Assignment`

**1 in Model**

```
class User  extends Model{

    protected $fillable = ['user_id',]; // your database fields that you allow to change

}
```

**2 in Request**

You can use `$request->only()` method to receive and neglect other which are not being used.

Comment: @Sneha Why do you want these dynamic?

Comment: @Sneha no, you can't. You can use `protected $guarded = []` and all model properties will be mass assignable. `$guarded` must be empty array.

Comment: Like we are handling it from a table if 1 more field is added then we need to add one more fields in $fillable ??

Comment: Can't we do it from the model is there any check for controller ?? because from model it would be more difficult to handle in that case..

Comment: @Sneha you cant do this. if you chnge ur database then you have to change fillable array too.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use session to store which field is already taken or stored.
Then every time you call your ajax you get the session then you remove the fields from `$request`

#### Here is a simple example

lets assume that user stored age and name fields

```
$request->session()->put('fields', [
        'age' => true,
        'name' => true
    ]);
```

Then every time that you post your form you first remove your session fields from `$request`

```
$fields = array_keys($request->session()->get('fields'));
$request->except($fields);
```

then you can proceed easily